# Binary Data with repetitions

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, binary-data

Why is Binomial data called Binary Data with repetitions? This is in context of Logistic Regression, where the response variable has a binomial distribution.

Comment: Can you provide more context in which this term was encountered?

Answer (score 1):

It is not. Such description would be ambiguous and misleading. You must have in mind models for binary data with repeated measurements (e.g. [as on those slides](http://publicifsv.sund.ku.dk/~jufo/courses/nfa2016/binary2015.pdf)), then you would have "binary data with repetitions". Otherwise, there is nothing "repeated" in binomial data, so calling standard binomial data (counts of "successes") like this would not make any sense. You could argue that binomial data is about $n$ trials, so the trials are repeated, but the same would be true for hypergeometric, or geometric distributions etc.

Comment: Isn't the r.v. following Binomial distribution $B(n,p)$ often interpreted as "the number of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials"? How isn't that a repetition?

Comment: @Digio but then *any* count data is data about repeated something...

Comment: Well yes, but unless the total number of independent trials is fixed and known, not all count data can be modelled as a Binomial experiment. So describing binomial data as "binary data with a fixed number of repetitions" would make sense to me.

Comment: @Digio what about hypergeometric distribution, for example?

Comment: In the hypergeometric distribution the trials are basically draws _without replacement_, therefore not independent. So if we were to restrict our description to Binomial data alone, we should update it to "binary data with a fixed number of independent repetitions", but then maybe it would be just simpler to stick to the original definition of a Binomial r.v... All I'm saying is that "binary data with repetitions" might be a bit abstract and non-technical but it's not completely nonsensical.

Comment: @Digio still "binary data with repetitions" *is* too ambiguous and misleading to describe binomially distributed data. Moreover, "repetitions" suggest some kind of repeated trials, what is pretty precisely defined in statistics.

Answer (score 1):

It is presumably in the sense that one $Y \sim \text{Bin}(n, \pi)$ random variable is the same thing as $n$ i.i.d. $Y_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\pi)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ (aka binary) random variables.

It is perhaps not such a good name, as one could get confused with the setting, where the same individual has a binary response measured at different times (which are correlated) with potentially different expected proportions. In that case treating the dependent binary random variables as independent random variables would be inappropriate.